# Modifying layout in custompackage/customtheme tutorial

Tags: theme, rwd-theme

I am new to Magento and have successfully completed the tutorial at `http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide`.
I'd like to start modifying the layout, specifically (to start) new.phtml to 
put up a list of courses instead of the standard pictures of products.  (Our
customer sells training courses not the standard products).  Could someone please
point me to another tutorial that explains exactly how to do this or, if the 
answer is fairly short, a description of the steps to take would be greatly 
appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set those images to be the product images and include a product list in the home page by adding `{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}` to the CMS page. Also, if you will only show those images in the home page, you could set "catalog/category/view/id/[your_category_id]" in Config -> General -> Web -> Default Pages -> Default Web URL.

Hope this helps.